# Is it sane to use the Factory Pattern to instantiate all widgets?

Tags: c++, user-interface, factory-pattern

I was looking into using the to implement the style and rendering in a little GUI toolkit of mine using the Factory Pattern, and then this crazy Idea struck me. Why not use the Factory Pattern for all widgets?

Right now I'm thinking something in style of:

```
Widget label = Widget::create("label", "Hello, World");
Widget byebtn = Widget::create("button", "Good Bye!");

byebtn.onEvent("click", &goodByeHandler);
```

New widget types would be registered with a function like `Widget::register(std::string ref, factfunc(*fact))`

What would you say is the pros and cons of this method?

I would bet on that there is almost no performance issues using a `std::map<std::string>` as it is only used when setting things up.

And yes, forgive me for being damaged by JavaScript and any possible syntax errors in my C++ as it was quite a while since I used that language.

---

Summary of pros and cons

Pros

- It would be easy to load new widgets dynamically from a file
- Widgets could easily be replaced on run-time (it could also assist with unit testing)
- Appeal to Dynamic People

Cons (and possible solutions)

- Not compile-time checked (Could write own build-time check. JS/Python/name it, is not compile-time checked either; and I believe that the developers do quite fine without it)
- Perhaps less performant (Do not need to create Widgets all the time. String Maps would not be used *all the time* but rather when creating the widget and registering event handlers)
- Up/Downcasting hell (Provide usual class instantiation where needed)
- Possible of making it harder to configure widgets (Make widgets have the same options)

---

My GUI Toolkit is in its early stages, it lacks quite much on the planning side. And as I'm not used to make GUI frameworks there is probably a lot of *questions*/design *decisions* that I have not even though of yet.

Right now I can't see that widgets would be too different in their set of methods, but that might rather just be because I've not gone trough the more advanced widgets in my mind yet.

Thank you all for your input!

Comment: I have come to the decision to have the Widget-factory interface in a separate branch from the normal interface. This way I can conduct experimentation there safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros

- It would be easy to read widgets from file or some other external source and create them by their names.

Cons

- It would be easy to pass incorrect type name into Widget::create and you'll get error in run-time only.
- You will have no access to widget-specific API without downcasting - i.e. one more source of run-time errors.
- It might be not that easy to find all places where you create a widget of particular type.

Why not get best of both worlds by allowing widget creation both with regular constructors and with a factory?

Comment: He could just as easily implement an external serializer object that calls the appropriate `create` member function based on the input data.

Comment: I like your compromise of using the best of both worlds. About the run-time error, an extra build step that does some checks would probably be quite straight-forward to create.

Comment: @Chet: surely he can, but it's much easier when you already have necessary code around. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not very intuitive. I would rather allow direct accesss to the classes. The question here is, why you want to have it this way. Is there any technical reason? Do you have a higher abstraction layer above the "real classes" that contain the widgets? 
For example, you have pure virtual classes for the outside API and then an implementation-class?
But it is difficult to say if this is any good without knowing how your library is set up, but I am not a big fan of factories myself, unless you really need them. 
If you have this higher abstraction layer and want that factory, take a look at irrlicht. It uses pure virtual classes for the API and then "implementation classes". The factory chooses the correct implementation depending on the chosen renderer (directx, opengl, software). 
But they don't identify the wanted class by a string. That's something I really wouldn't do in C++.
Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks, I will go and take a look of irrlicht. I can't really say that there is any technical reasons to use the factory pattern in the way I'm thinking of, rather it just feels like a good way to implement the API. It would for example allow me to load widgets from files and perhaps even replace the standard ones on-the-fly.

I'm also quite used to how JavaScript works by now and how beautiful it is with it's dynamic properties.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise *against* using a `string` as a key, and promote a real method for each subtype.

```
class Factory
{
public:
  std::unique_ptr<Label> createLabel(std::string const& v);
  std::unique_ptr<Button> createButton(std::string const& v, Action const* a);
};
```

This has several advantages:

- Compiler-checked, you could mispell the string, but you cannot get a running program with a mispelled method
- More precise return type, and thus, no need for up-casting (and all its woes)
- More precise parameters, for not all elements require the same set of parameters

Generally, this is done to allow customization. If `Factory` is an abstract interface, then you can have several implementations (`Windows`, `GTK`, `Mac`) that create them differently under the hood.

Then, instead of setting up one creator function per type, you would switch the whole factory at once.

*Note: performance-wise, virtual functions are much faster than map-lookup by string key*

Comment: Regarding the performance, I do not expect that one would constantly change any of the widgets parameters or create new widgets all the time. So the added overhead may be negligible.

Comment: @Frank: you forget that any time you *get* a widget, you incur the performance overhead of a map lookup. That being said, I much more worried about compile-time checking than runtime performance.

Comment: I does not quite get what you mean, sure there would be a performance overhead when one instantiates a widget with `Widget::create` but for all further access a normal pointer would be used. I am not too concerned myself about the compile-time checking, one would probably be able to add a replacement check as part of the build procedure - it might not be as good as if the compiler is watching your back, but it's at least something.

Comment: @Frank: but why get to all the trouble of scripting yourself when the compiler could do it for you :) ? As for the performance, yes the overhead is only incurred on creation. But don't focus on performance yet, you're unlikely to hit that wall, focus on ease of use/debugging first.